# Changing form action location

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the form action location Depending on what user selects:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="verify(event,this)">
    <input id="fileToUpload" name="fileToUpload"type="file"/>
    Select File
    <input id="filesToUpload" name="filesToUpload" type="file" webkitdirectory directory multiple/>
    Select Folder
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit" class="cfu">
</form>
```

Function is:

```
   function verify(e,t){
    if(!document.getElementById("fileToUpload").value){
        document.uploadForm.action = "zipping.php";
        t.submit();
    }
    else{
        t.submit();
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: are you getting a hit to verify function?

Comment: Its better to write if(document.getE...value != true) in javascript language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, form properties on the `document` object are by `name`, not `id`:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" name="uploadForm" ...
                                        ^---here
```

Also, if you're not preventing the form from submitting, you don't need to call `.submit()` on anything (if that even works in the first place):

```
function verify(e,t){
    if(!document.getElementById("fileToUpload").value){
        document.uploadForm.action = "zipping.php";
    }
}
```

Demo, which will of course produce a 404 but you can examine the requested URL in your debugging tools:

```html
<form action="upload.php" method="post" name="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="verify(event,this)">
  <input id="fileToUpload" name="fileToUpload"type="file"/>
    Select File
  <input id="filesToUpload" name="filesToUpload" type="file" webkitdirectory directory multiple/>
    Select Folder
  <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit" class="cfu">
</form>
<script>
function verify(e,t){
    if(!document.getElementById("fileToUpload").value){
        document.uploadForm.action = "zipping.php";
    }
}
</script>
```